# how do I know the data type of database field using PHP,.?

Tags: php, solr, sqldatatypes

I want to know how I can get the datatype of each field in a SQL database using PHP;
I want use this datatype for creating some docs in SOLR.

For Example:

```
if (datatype == int) then "[field_name] + _i".
```

So, if I have field `bedrooms` and the datatype is `integer`, in SOLR I'll save this field to be `bedrooms_i`.

Comment: Why are the names of your database fields based on the data-type?

Comment: Steve Lewis: yes, I used MySql
Oli: I think it's not like that, I'll use it for SOLR, so the field name in solr is based on the data-type in database..
thanks for the answer,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysql_fetch_field()` to retrieve metadata about fields.

```
mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db('database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  your_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);    

$i = 0;
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
{
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);   
    echo "<pre>".print_r($meta,TRUE)."</pre>";
    $i++;
}
```

Here `$meta->type` will give you the field type.

Comment: can use this for query result,.?
because, I've joined multiple table, and then I need the data-types of all field that I get with that query,.
thanks for the answer,.

Comment: hei, thanks Vikk, it's work,.
Sorry I can't vote up your answer, my reputation still not enough,. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the [SHOW COLUMN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)S to get the name, data type, etc. of all fields/columns in a table.

Comment: is there other function to do this,.?
because in my query, I joined more table, so if any function that can get the datatype from query result, it will helps me a lot,.
btw, thanks for your answer,.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, I'll assume MySQL.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, {ETC...}
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database' AND
    TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'
```

Comment: can I use this for query result,.? because, I've joined multiple table, and then I need the data-types of all field that I get with that query,. thanks for the answer,.